# Python string binary bitwise operation

Tags: python, string, bitwise-operators

how can I do the string binary bitwise operation?
my code:

```
filename = sys.argv[0]
input = sys.argv[1]
a =  sys.argv[2]
b = sys.argv[3:]
r = b[2:]
c = input[:4]
d = input[4:]

for i in range(0, int(a))   
    e = c & d
    f = c ^ r[i]

print(e)
print(f)
```

my input is: `xx.py 10101010 3 1001 0101 0011`

I don't know how to get e,f for the string to do bitwise operations in binary.

Comment: What is the expected output of this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a string representation of a binary number as follows:

```
binary_string = '1010101'

print(int(binary_string, 2))
```

The value 2 is the base. The default is 10

Comment: Yeap, this is a good way to do that, but there is a problem for this way, it  is deleting the first three values in the four bits if I input the 00010001... except my first position of the input is 1 , the function is right.

Comment: I got it, print('{:04b}'.format(e)